# Matching columns with string values that are not 100% identical for Dataframe Merging

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, merge, python-re

I am trying to Merge Two data-frames and unfortunately the only common columns are the Name columns and they don't have 100% identical values. Is there a way I can match the names based on a probability, lets say if there is 80% or more matching strings between two values, they would match them together. below is an example of what I face;

```
df1= pd.DataFrame({"Name":["John", "Mary", "Sarah", "Jack"], "B":[1,2,3,4]})
df2= pd.DataFrame({"Name":["Jon", 'Mary", "Sara", "Jak", "lilly"], "C":["foo", "bar", "bar", "foo", "bar"]})
```

I am fairly new to coding and I would appreciate your advice :)

Comment: Look at [fuzzywuzzy](https://pypi.org/project/fuzzywuzzy/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't require anything too fancy, the built-in `difflib.get_close_matches` may suffice:

```
from difflib import get_close_matches

def get_closest_match(name):
    matches = get_close_matches(name, df1['Name']
    if len(matches) > 0:
        return matches[0]
    else:
        return None

df2['ClosestName'] = df2['Name'].apply(get_closest_match)
df1.merge(df2, left_on='Name', right_on='ClosestName')
```

Result:

```
Name_x  B Name_y    C ClosestName
  John  1    Jon  foo        John
  Mary  2   Mary  bar        Mary
 Sarah  3   Sara  bar       Sarah
  Jack  4    Jak  foo        Jack
```

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @Scott Boston, you can do using fuzzywuzzy package. You need to create a new column which would contain the most similar word from the df1 and then you can join on that column.

```
In [88]: df2['key'] = df2['Name'].apply(lambda x : [process.extract(x, df1['Name'], limit=1)][0][0][0])

In [89]: df2
Out[89]:
    Name    C    key
0    Jon  foo   John
1   Mary  bar   Mary
2   Sara  bar  Sarah
3    Jak  foo   Jack
4  lilly  bar   Mary

In [90]: df2.merge(df1, left_on='key',right_on='Name')
Out[90]:
  Name_x    C    key Name_y  B
0    Jon  foo   John   John  1
1   Mary  bar   Mary   Mary  2
2  lilly  bar   Mary   Mary  2
3   Sara  bar  Sarah  Sarah  3
4    Jak  foo   Jack   Jack  4
```

Comment: I tried both solutions but they tend to find matches at the simplest commonalities, this is unfortunately not working. I heard of a library called "recordlinking", any advise on that?

Answer (score 1):

There may be two solutions.

The first solution works if you have all the valid names (namespace) for the column "Name". Then you can iterate the values in the column "Name" and:

1. Calculate its distance with all the possible value in the namespace (Levenshtein distance should works)
2. Select the one with minimum distance (highest similarity) and replace with it
   2.5 To avoid error-prone replacement, you can set a cutoff for the distance
3. Just merging (outer join)

For the case that you do not have all the valid names, you can create a set with all the values from the column "Name" of the other data frame and regard it as the namespace. The following steps are the same.